# How to use offline Plotly and Pyramid to update a plot without reloading the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pyramid, plotly

I am trying to reload an offline Plotly graph based on some user selection on a webpage. I am using Pyramid to generate the webpage. When the user input has been captured, I use the following jQuery to generate content for a div:

```
$.getJSON("{{ request.route_url('park_list') }}" + "feature_plot/feature_ids=" + ids_string, function(data) {
    document.getElementById("plotly").innerHTML = data.result;
});
```

The first parameter of the getJSON is based on Jinja2 templating, where a url is retrieved. The output from there is a json dictionary with a "result" key/value pair. The value is the div content, i.e. a Plotly graph. This I then attempt to insert into a div container called "plotly".

The problem is that nothing is inserted. I see an empty block of width 0 and if I try to fix the width, this is successful, but there is still no visible content.

My question is: What is the proper way to dynamically update an offline Plotly, without reloading the page?

Comment: Please show your Pyramid view code that receives your json call.  It also might be helpful to show the generated html URL of the json call.

Comment: Just construct the data/fig json in python send it via ajax then use `plotly.react()` to update the graph as explained in [https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyplot plotlyjs api]. It's by no means harder but more effecient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Firefox Web developer console > Network tab to inspect the resulting HTTP response payload. Most likely it is not JSON or it does not contain `result` attribute, making the `getJSON` to fail.

For ghetto debugging you can also do:

```
console.log(data);
```

... before trying insert HTML.

Also if your goal is just to replace HTML element on the page through AJAX call where the resulting HTML is rendered on the server side, you can simply do:

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
    $("#myelem").replace(html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me find a better solution for the problem, where I only send a couple of variables through Pyramid, but use JS Plotly code instead of Python code to generate the figures.